# OpenSSL AES cant decrypt

Tags: .net, encryption, openssl, aes, clr

i have e problem to decrypt a openssl aes encrypted text.

the following codeblock shows you how i encrypt my text. Over CLI i send a managed string to encrypt and the key for this. When i use the key which i use to encrypt at the same funktion it works wonderfully. When i look at the dec_out in same function the decrypted value is the same as the input.

```
const int keyLength = 256;
String^ cryptoLib::CLIWrapper::encrypt(String^ text, String^ key)
{

std::string unmanagedText = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(text);
std::string unmanagedKey = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(key);
const unsigned char* inputArray = (unsigned char*)(unmanagedText.c_str());
const unsigned char* keyArray = (unsigned char*)(unmanagedKey.c_str());
size_t inputLength = unmanagedText.length();

const size_t encslength = ((inputLength + AES_BLOCK_SIZE) / AES_BLOCK_SIZE) * AES_BLOCK_SIZE;
unsigned char *enc_out = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) *encslength);
unsigned char *dec_out = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) *encslength);
memset(enc_out, 0, sizeof(encslength));
memset(dec_out, 0, sizeof(dec_out));

AES_KEY  dec_key, enc_key;
AES_set_encrypt_key(keyArray, keyLength, &enc_key);
AES_encrypt(inputArray, enc_out, &enc_key);
//Decrypt in same function works!
AES_set_decrypt_key(keyArray, keyLength, &dec_key);
AES_decrypt(enc_out, dec_out, &dec_key);
//test in other function
decrypt("", key, enc_out, encslength, inputLength);
std::string output = std::string(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(dec_out));
String^ returnValue = msclr::interop::marshal_as<String^>(output);



return returnValue;
}
```

But when i send the encryptedtext to another function it doesnt works. Here you can see the decryption function. I call it from the first function after encryption with the same managed key.

```
String ^ cryptoLib::CLIWrapper::decrypt(String ^ encText, String^ key,        
unsigned char* enc_out, size_t encLength, size_t inputLength)
{
std::string unmanagedKey = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(key);
const unsigned char* keyArray = (unsigned char*)(unmanagedKey.c_str());
unsigned char *dec_out = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)                
*encLength);
memset(dec_out, 0, sizeof(dec_out));

AES_KEY  dec_key, enc_key;
AES_set_decrypt_key(keyArray, keyLength, &dec_key);
AES_decrypt(enc_out, dec_out, &enc_key);



return "";
}
```

Can anyone help me what i doing wrong ?

Comment: Why do you run your own implementation when there are plenty of wrappers for pretty much anything readily available?

Comment: Need to encrypt on PC side and decrypt on Android side. At Android the decrypt must be make on C. It´s easier for me, when i use the same lib at both sides.

Comment: The chance that you get it wrong(security-wise and coding-wise), if you fiddle with something that a language is not designed for is way higher than just formally specifying the encryption-method you want to use and then search two libraries specifically written for each language with nice API's and support.

Comment: You should *not* use `AES_encrypt` and friends. That's a software-only implementation, so you will not enjoy hardware support, like AES-NI. You should be using `EVP_*` functions. See [EVP Symmetric Encryption and Decryption](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki. In fact, you should probably be using authenticated encryption because it provides *both* confidentiality and authenticity. See [EVP Authenticated Encryption and Decryption](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: atm i want to implement the EVP Symmetric algorithm. But the same problem. When i decrypt with the same key with which i do the encryption the decryption is no problem. But when i init a new key with the same chars but other address, the decryption fails..... i have no idea why

Comment: Code like this looks wrong: `String^ returnValue = msclr::interop::marshal_as<String^>(output);` Embedded NULLs probably means the string is being truncated. You have to use the `{ptr, len}` pair because of the embedded NULLs.

Comment: *I want to implement the EVP Symmetric algorithm. But the same problem."* - You should take a quick look at [EVP Symmetric Encryption and Decryption | C++ Programs](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption#C.2B.2B_Programs) to see how length and strings are managed.